# Boundary Conditions for Sine Gordon on some $K< 0$ surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

The Sine-Gordon equation 
$$ \alpha^{\prime \prime}(s) = \sin \alpha (s) $$
defines asymptotic lines of all constant negatively Gauss curvature $K$ surfaces on a Chebyshev net in 3-space or so I understand.

While the surfaces of revolution solutions are available in text book,
what must be plugged in as *correct boundary conditions* for other surfaces like:

Kuen surfaces

Stationary pseudospherical surfaces

Breather surfaces

and

Twisted central pseudosphere or Dini? I searched for relations $(\phi, \psi) $   (normal, tangential rotations) no luck so far, appreciate all guidance and advice.

Comment: I did not mention about ODE /PDE. In rotationally symmetric special cases we can reduce the PDE to ODE with a single constant. I could not find boundary condition to evaluate the plethora of 1 and 2 solitons given in Wiki  ...  at any rate am unable to find boundary  conditions even for the above surfaces  either as PDE  or ODE on $ \phi, \psi = \alpha/2 $.

Comment: Thanks, @Deane Yang Yes I have done that successfully at the cuspidal edge start and had no problem plotting symmetrical cases. (Shall upload an image if you care to see).  But in non-symmetrical  cases it does not help.I do not prefer to plot available closed form solutions in case of Breather or Kuen.

Comment: Let me try;  and the same holds for Breathers  also?

Comment: @DeaneYang I have a suggestion , as there are no comments from others.  I copied your valued comments and wish to delete all my comments.  Suggest you also do likewise . This way comments area is clean, has served its purpose  and would be ok with moderator.

Comment: One possible place to specify boundary conditions is where the surface becomes singular (say, a cusp). This is where one of the principal curvatures blows up. If you have explicit formulas for an embedding, you should be able to identify where this is. This is also where each asymptotic direction converges to one of the principal directions.